# how to disable the svn function of xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode, svn

The xcode 4.5 has integrate svn function. But I don't like this features. It always confilct with other svn tools. And be freeze when building . I can see svn thread from Activity Monitor.

I try to delete the information from Organizer---Repositories. but it doesn't work wery well.
It will automatic add some information to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rename the `IDESubversion.ideplugin` package (located in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/` (for example rename to `IDESubversion-xxx.ideplugin`).